# Boostrapped histogram of RMSE for XGBoost Regression H2o R (How to make it more efficient)

Tags: r

I want to construct the histogram and CI for RMSE using XGBoost regression H2O. The codes given below are (reproducible) and work fine on a small iteration to 100. However, I want to iterate at least 1000 and the dataset is large. When a large number of iteration such as even 500 I get the following error message. Can we apply the lapply function to make it fast? or Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page, : Unexpected CURL error: Empty reply from server

```
boston <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/gbm_test/BostonHousing.csv")

# set the predictor names and the response column name
predictors <- colnames(boston)[1:13]
# set the response column to "medv" 
response <- "medv"

# convert the chas column to a factor bounds river; 0 otherwise))
boston["chas"] <- as.factor(boston["chas"])

rmse=c()

for(i in 1:50){

  boston.splits <- h2o.splitFrame(data =  boston, ratios = c(0.6, 0.2))
  train<- boston.splits[[1]]
  valid<- boston.splits[[2]]
  test<- boston.splits[[3]]

my_xgb1 <- h2o.xgboost(x = predictors, 
                       y = response,
                       nfolds = 0,
                       training_frame = train,
                       validation_frame = valid,
                        stopping_tolerance  = 0.005,
                       max_runtime_secs = 3600,
                       seed = 1601,
                       distribution =   "AUTO",
                       tweedie_power    = 1.5,
                       categorical_encoding = "AUTO",
                       quiet_mode   = TRUE,
                       ntrees   = 100,
                       max_depth    = 6,
                       min_rows = 0.01,
                       min_child_weight =   1,
                       learn_rate   =0.05,
                       grow_policy  = "depthwise" ,
                       booster  = "gbtree",
                       reg_lambda   = 0.1,
                       reg_alpha    = 1)


pred <- h2o.predict(my_xgb1 , test)
perf <- h2o.performance(my_xgb1, newdata = test)

rmse[i] = h2o.rmse(perf)
print(rmse)
}
mean(rmse)
ci <- quantile(rmse, c(.05, .95)) 
windows()
# Plot histogram of scores.
hist(rmse, density=35, main = "Test RMSE over 50 Samples", xlab = "Value of Obtained RMSE", col="blue", border="black")
abline(v=mean(rmse), lwd=3, col="red")
```